# No Speedup in Float Multiply with Rust SSE Intrinsics

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, sse, avx2

I'm trying an experiment with intrinsics in Rust where I make a big vector of floats, then record the time it takes to multiply all of them by a constant.  Next I try the same thing with SSE intrinsics.  On a relatively new laptop with 50 million floats, it comes out to about 23ms either way.  When I do something similar with AVX, it's even slower, like 67ms.  I allocate all the memory I need for both the input and output before I start the timer.

Here's how I do it with simple `f32`s:

```
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
let x: Vec<f32> = (0..N).map(|_| rng.gen::<i16>() as f32).collect();

let mut z_native: Vec<f32> = (0..N).map(|_| 0.0).collect();

let t0 = Instant::now();
for i in 0..N {
    *z_native.get_unchecked_mut(i) = *x.get_unchecked(i) * std::f32::consts::PI;
}
println!("Native {:?}", t0.elapsed());
```

Here's how I do it with SSE:

```
let mut x_sse: Vec<__m128> = vec![];
let y_sse: __m128 = x86_64::_mm_set_ps1(std::f32::consts::PI);
let mut z_sse: Vec<__m128> = vec![];

for i in 0..(N/4) {
    x_sse.push(x86_64::_mm_set_ps(
        x[(i*4)+3], x[(i*4)+2],
        x[(i*4)+1], x[(i*4)+0],
    ));
    z_sse.push(x86_64::_mm_setzero_ps());
}

let t0 = Instant::now();
for i in 0..(N/4) {
    *z_sse.get_unchecked_mut(i) = x86_64::_mm_mul_ps(*x_sse.get_unchecked(i), y_sse);
}
println!("SSE {:?}", t0.elapsed());
```

Is there something I'm missing about how this is supposed to work?  I know about how the memory alignment makes a difference, but I read that `Vec` is always aligned on the size of whatever it contains.  I also print out randomly-selected values from the results at the end to make sure they don't somehow get optimized out.  Thanks!

Edit:
I built with `cargo run --release` so I don't know exactly what compiler flags I'm using, but it's whatever Cargo defaults to in release mode.

Comment: This is trivial for a compiler to auto-vectorize, so the asm you're comparing against is already using SIMD.  If you're lucky, Rustc manages to optimize that `_mm_set_ps` of four contiguous elements into one `_mm_loadu_ps` but if not it'll be a total disaster of shuffle instructions.  I guess that's outside the timed loop, but IDK why you're doing that in the first place.  Are you compiling with full optimization enabled, like `-C opt-level=3 -target-cpu=x86-64-v3`?  (Or maybe just baseline CPU to stop the compiler from using AVX if your intrinsics aren't.)

Comment: Also, 50M floats are too big for even L3 cache, and you're copying rather than updating in place, so you're close to a memory bottleneck even with scalar asm.  See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) re: possible issues. It looks like you are writing `z_sse` before the timed region so you shouldn't be getting page faults, unless those dead stores somehow got optimized away.

Comment: Anyway, I'd expect at best equal speed to auto-vectorized code for this, for 50M elements.  The only mystery is why your AVX version would be slower.

Comment: Did you compile with AVX enabled? (`-Ctarget-feature=+avx`).

Comment: If you try using AVX instructions without AVX enabled will you get a runtime exception? I'm using the defaults so I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: In C/C++, clang (like GCC) won't let you compile code using `_mm256_loadu_ps` or whatever without telling the compiler it's allowed to use AVX.  I don't know how rustc handles that, but I'd guess it's the same since they both use the LLVM back-end.  No special asm instructions are needed in a user-space process for AVX instructions to not fault; enabling AVX is something the OS kernel does.